# Anti-alias is not working with circular scrollbar

Tags: tizen, tizen-native-app

In Tizen5.5, I have created a (circular)genlist to have the nice circular scrollbar.

But for some wierd reason, the scrollbar is not anti-aliased :O on my real device.

**Fact1:** On emulator it works.

**Fact2:** on real device, system apps which has this scrollbar, all work fine (anit-aliased).

**Fact3:** it is not happening all time, only when I scroll the genlist downwards.

Here is the result (see the scrollbar):

[image]

Here is my code to reproduce:

```
/* Circle surface */
ad->circle_surface = eext_circle_surface_naviframe_add(ad->naviframe);

/* Genlist */
ad->genlist = elm_genlist_add(ad->naviframe);
elm_genlist_mode_set(ad->genlist, ELM_LIST_COMPRESS);
elm_genlist_homogeneous_set(ad->genlist, EINA_TRUE);
evas_object_size_hint_weight_set(ad->genlist, EVAS_HINT_EXPAND, EVAS_HINT_EXPAND);
evas_object_size_hint_align_set(ad->genlist, EVAS_HINT_FILL, EVAS_HINT_FILL);

ad->circle_genlist = eext_circle_object_genlist_add(ad->genlist, ad->circle_surface);
eext_circle_object_genlist_scroller_policy_set(ad->circle_genlist, ELM_SCROLLER_POLICY_ON, ELM_SCROLLER_POLICY_ON);
eext_rotary_object_event_activated_set(ad->circle_genlist, EINA_TRUE);

/* Item classes */
ad->itc_padding = elm_genlist_item_class_new();
ad->itc_padding->item_style = "padding";

ad->itc_item = elm_genlist_item_class_new();
ad->itc_item->item_style = "1text";

elm_genlist_item_append(ad->genlist, ad->itc_padding, NULL, NULL, ELM_GENLIST_ITEM_NONE, NULL, NULL);

// add content - Item Style */
ad->itc_item->func.text_get = getListItemText;

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    elm_genlist_item_append(ad->genlist, ad->itc_item, NULL, NULL, ELM_GENLIST_ITEM_NONE, NULL, NULL);
}

// add footer padding
elm_genlist_item_append(ad->genlist, ad->itc_padding, NULL, NULL, ELM_GENLIST_ITEM_NONE, NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: Which device do you use? I would like to reproduce this on my side.

Comment: Is it able to attach your project here? I could not make same view you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with help of *raster* from IRC.

All I had to do is to ask for HW rendering:

```
elm_config_accel_preference_set("hw:depth:stencil");
```

After adding this single line all anti-aliasing issues are solved.

Comment: I think app no need to care gl depth and stencil ..
below API call would be better.

elm_config_accel_preference_set("gl");

Comment: I took this config directly from the comments in source. Why do you *think* setting to `gl` is better? Better in which terms? Thanks

Comment: hmm without this config it should works well in actual wearable devices.
SDK emulator works software render only as some issues... but in devices default render engine will be gl and hardware accelation should work.